# How to copy a filename from a column and search for it in a destination and save it to new location with different name?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for someone to help me with a VBA code which could help me locate a file in a destination using the filename in a column in excel, and copy the file and save it in another destination and rename it with a filename from another column.

So, for instance I have a column A in a sheet 1, having names `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`,... I have to search this filenames from a group of files from a destination, say `C:/Users/Images/` and copy them to a different location `C:/Users/New_location/` and rename them as per the column B in the same sheet 1 to lets say, `1_new.jpg`, `2_new.jpg`.

I have created a code which copies the files to a destination but I cannot create one to rename it.

However, I could rename it manually using a VBA code. But I want to automate it.

Please find the manual code below:-

```
Sub test()
  Dim R As Range
  Dim SourcePath As String, DestPath As String, FName As String, NewFName As String
  Dim Cell As Range
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim i As Integer


  'Setup source and dest path (Note: must have a trailing backslash!)
  SourcePath = "E:\Praveen\Images_Final\"
  DestPath = "E:\Praveen\Copy_Test\"
  'Visit each used cell in column A



    FName = Range("M2").Value
    NewFName = Range("N2").Value

  FileCopy SourcePath & FName, DestPath & NewFName
    FName = Range("M3").Value
    NewFName = Range("N3").Value
  FileCopy SourcePath & FName, DestPath & NewFName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code. It will work

**Note:** If the file does not exist in the source folder then it will throw the Popup message.

```
Sub test()
    Dim SourcePath, DestPath, Fname, NewFName
    SourcePath = "E:\Praveen\Images_Final\"
    DestPath = "E:\Praveen\Copy_Test\"
    For i = 2 To 3
        Fname = Range("M" & i).Value
        NewFName = Range("N" & i).Value
        If Not Dir(SourcePath & Fname, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
            FileCopy SourcePath & Fname, DestPath & NewFName
        Else
            MsgBox (Fname & " Not Exists in Folder")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I was running my head around it for a week!

Comment: Thanks, Karthick! It was very helpful!